# Can I drag a grappled creature and release it after moving half of my speed, then move the remainder of my speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, grapple, forced-movement

The [grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) rules state:

> #### Moving a Grappled Creature.
>
> When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

If I have 30 speed and have an enemy grappled, then I move 15 feet and release my grapple on my target, do I still have 15 feet of movement left, or is it lost for the round?

Comment: Related: [How does Spirit Guardians impact available movement for affected creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84246/how-does-spirit-guardians-impact-available-movement-for-affected-creatures/84247#84247), which also refers to a temporary condition that halves your speed, and how it works during your turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## After releasing the grapple, you can move 15 more feet

#### Movement speed is only halved while you are dragging the  creature

> When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

The condition is clear, when you move with a grappled creature your speed is halved. If you are no longer moving with a grappled creature, this rule no longer applies and your speed returns to normal.

#### When your speed changes, the amount you can move also changes

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed.

This is a simple rule and it has no qualifiers. During one round you can move up to whatever your **current speed** is. It doesn't mention any exceptions for cases where your speed might increase or decrease during the turn.

So, the rule simply is:

$$ \text{movementLeft} = \text{currentSpeed} - \text{movementUsed} $$

If your speed increases during your turn (for example if you cast *haste* on yourself), you can move further that round. If it decreases, so does the distance you can move.

Thus, if you move 15 feet with your grappled creature you have moved 15 feet with a speed of 15.

$$ \text{movementLeft} = (30/2) - 15 = 0 $$
After releasing the grapple, your speed becomes 30.

$$ \text{movementLeft} = 30 - 15 = 15 $$
And, according to the rules, you can move a distance up to your speed on your turn. Since you have already moved 15 and you have a speed of 30, you have 15 feet more you can go.

#### *Haste* as an alternate example

Consider the case of *haste* used mid-turn. *Haste* doubles the target's speed. Consider a creature that moved up to its current speed, saw a need to move further and then cast *haste* on itself.

It doesn't make sense for the creature to not be able to move further now that they have a new speed. After all, if they had cast it at the beginning of their turn they would have been able to move the full distance just fine. Why does it matter that they cast it after moving part of the way?

The above ruling correctly (IMO) allows the creature to move the appropriate amount of spaces because movement is continuously calculated off the current speed of the creature. When the speed changes, so does the amount of movement no matter when that change occurs.

#### Difficult terrain uses a different calculation that does not apply here

Conditions such a difficult terrain use very different rules and language for describing how movement is penalized.

> Every foot of movement costs one extra foot

This is not how the moving a grappled creature rules are written at all and they aren't the same as this question demonstrates. Without language like this in the rule for grappled creatures, there is no rules support for calculating the movement the same way. Whether or not this was intentional, only the designers can say. Barring errata, this is the RAW ruling that we have.

As always, if a DM wants to change a rule, they can do so. In this case, changing the rule such that dragging is treated like difficult terrain would probably not be something that has any noticeable effect on game-enjoyment (but it isn't something I've tested).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86772/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-enkryptor).

Comment: Due to the fact that effects like from Difficult Terrain (Movement costs 1 extra foot of speed) are written differently than how movement while Grappling is written, it's best assumed that they're interpreted as having different outcomes.  To assume that Grappling and Difficult Terrain have the same effect would almost imply the Grappling rules are written incorrectly, which is impossible to prove. As this currently is the only answer that provides a different outcome than Difficult Terrain, this seems to be the most accurately interpreted answer, until errata or Sage Advice says otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106647/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-phil-s).

Comment: Shouldn't the formula for calculating remaining movement  be, in this case, ((30/2)-15)x2=0, or ((St/2)-Dm)x2=Dr where St is total speed, Dm is distance moved (while grappling), and Dr is distance remaining? I ask this since in the example still moved Dm while grappled, meaning (I think) you should perform that operation before correcting for a later modification to speed. This could be important because now if you move 14 feet you have 2 feet of movement remaining, instead of the 16 feet proposed by your answer, or the 1 foot if you were still grappling.

Answer (score 39):

### You can't move, since you have zero movement left

You can release the target at any time, effectively changing your speed:

> you can release the target whenever you like (no action required)

You will get your normal *speed*, but you won't get your *movement* back. In 5e "speed" is not equal "movement". For example, if your walking speed is 30ft, you can move up to 30 feet per turn; when you moved 30 feet, your speed is still 30, but now you have 0 movement.

See these related questions for details:

- [Does Grappling Halve Your Remaining Speed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80311/)
- [How Do Grapplers Stand If Prone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79392/)

After you moved 15 feet with 15ft speed you have 0 movement left. Even if you get faster speed afterwards, it won't give you any extra movement (otherwise, you could move your normal 30 feet this round, regardless of the fact that your speed was halved).

@Slagmoth added a fair point here:

> I honestly think the devs used a poor word choice on this. It would be easier to think about it the same way as difficult terrain which would be that it costs you twice as much to move a given distance as opposed to halving your speed.

For the sake of simplicity, you shouldn't use two different methods (one for difficult terrain, another one for grappling) for calculating a similar slowness effect. It seems [Mike Mearls](https://twitter.com/mikemearls) uses [the same ruling](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/09/02/caltrop/):

> Things like caltrop/ball bearings ref to moving at half speed how do you do that? Treating each 5' as 10 like difficult terain?
>
> yes, essentially pay an extra 1' per 1' moved

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86781/discussion-on-answer-by-enkryptor-can-i-release-my-grapple-after-moving-half-of).

Comment: By "should be" do you mean you think it should be written that way or that the rules actually are written that way now?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I mean, the GM should treat it that way. I think this question cannot be answered only by strict RAW reading, so we have to apply 5e design philosophy and common sense.

Comment: @enkryptor could you add that to your answer? I feel like that would be useful to know and would tie everything together. Normally when you make big leaps from the rules it is good to say so  so you don't come across as making assertions of what the rules actually say. It is good to point out when RAW is insufficient or confusing.

Comment: There is no point where grapple spends that movement, it doesn't matter that you don't get it back. Speed is what determines your movement that you can spend, compare for example: Your grapple movement speed is 15 and if you switch to your walking movement speed it is 30 and you can still move 15. The same way that if your walking speed is 30 you can walk 30 and then still use your flying movement speed of 60, and still move another 30 by flying, but not by walking.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, and I think you could quote sprint in your answer to further show how movement works. "When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up..."
A lot of people claim sprint simply doubles your speed, but it explicitly does not, it gives you extra movement to use that round, further suggesting that movement is a finite resource and simply changing your speed that turn will not change it.

Answer (score 6):

## No.  When you move with a grappled creature your speed is halved.

**tl;dr** As soon a character moves with a grappled creature, your speed is halved.  Releasing the creature does not undo the halved movement for the round.

### [Movement and speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition)

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed

When you halve the speed, you halve the distance that can be moved on a turn.

### How [grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) affects the distance a character can move.

The act of moving a grappled creature halves your move speed.  There is no provision for releasing a grappled creature along the way returning the move speed lost.

> Moving a Grappled Creature. When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

E.g.

1. A character with move speed 30 begins to drag a grappled creature.
2. The move speed is now halved to 15.
3. The character moves 5 feet and releases the creature.
4. The character has 10 feet of move remaining.

Specifically answering the above situation:  The character begins to drag a grappled creature.  Their speed is halved to 15.  They move 15 feet.  They release the creature.  They have 0 (15-15) movement remaining.  Dragging the creature halved their movement.

### Grapple is not [using different move speeds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#UsingDifferentSpeeds).

If grapple were a separate move speed, then a character could use both in the way the question describes.

Comment: With your example, would moving 15 feet and then grappling allow an additional 15, 7.5, or 0 feet?

Comment: @DanielZastoupil Added a section to specifically address the situation in the posted question.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil if you move 15 of 30 move speed, then grapple, you still have 15 move remaining.  If you move 15 of 30, grapple, then try to drag the creature, your move speed is halved and you have 0 remaining.

Comment: So, in a sense, your understanding of it is that grappling halves the player's maximum speed, and if the player's current speed is higher than the maximum, their current speed drops to the new maximum.

Comment: You might want to make clear that in your interpretation, releasing the grapple has no effect on your move speed, and that it is still halved until your next turn. As-is it is implied but not stated.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil there is the amount already moved and movement speed. A character can move up to their movement speed. So if movement speed minus moved is 0 or less, they cannot move anymore.

Comment: Dragging doesn't half their movement, it halfs their speed. (30/2)x2-15 is 15 at point of release - if by some happenstance they would grapple them again, then 30/2-15 would be 0.

Comment: @Akixkisu I may be missing the distinct you're making between movement and speed.  "On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed".  When you half your speed, you halve the distance you can move.  Also, what is the source of the multiplication by 2 in the expression?

Comment: Your base walking speed of 30 is halfed while you grapple, it returns to its base once the grapple ends. Speed determines movement (aside from a few exceptions), movement does not determine speed. I think the section on Being Prone (PHB 190-191) showcases this best.

Comment: @Akixkisu I see.  The expression is subtracting the distanced moved at the end. Ignoring changes to speed during the movement and only dealing with the final speed at the end.  That would be an entirely different take on the matter and bears expounding upon in a separate answer.

Comment: Not quiet, though I'd be curious on what basis you conclude that grapple is not using different move speeds.

Comment: @Akixkisu The way it's written simply halves move speed.  It does not create a new one such as flying and swimming nor a different valuation for movement such as difficult terrain or crawling while prone.

Comment: Would you agree that 15 and 30 are different speeds and that you can break up your movement on your turn? It halves your speed, not your movement. When things cost you extra movement, then they say so.

Comment: Your last paragraph - "For example, if you have a speed of 30 and a flying speed of 60 because a wizard cast the fly spell on you, you could fly 20 feet, then walk 10 feet, and then leap into the air to fly 30 feet more." ...this means you flew for 1/3rd of your available movement, then walked for a further 1/3rd of your movement, and finally flew for a further 1/2 of your available movement. Doesn't add up.

Comment: @PhilS that is an astute observation.  I quoted the basic rules there.  I'm going to submit a query to WoTC about that section.  It seems that they take the highest move speed and apply it to all since 20+10+30 totals the 60 foot fly speed even though they had a walk in there.

Comment: @GcL I think at bullet 4 in your example you may have meant to type 20 feet remaining, not 10. By dragging 5 feet, he used up 10 and so 20 of the 30' remain.

Answer (score 2):

For any portion of your turn that you have a creature grappled, you're spending 2 feet of movement for any 1 foot you want to travel.

Difficult Terrain specifically says: You move at **half speed** in difficult terrain--moving 1 foot in difficult terrain costs 2 feet of speed--so you can cover only half the normal distance in a minute, an hour, or a day.

Grapple specifically says: When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your **speed is halved**, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

The text of Difficult Terrain defines what "speed is halved/move at half speed" means.

If you have a creature grappled, and you have a normal move speed of 30', and you move 10', you've spent 20 of your move speed (or movement for the turn). If you then release the grapple (which is a free action), you have 10' left, which you spend 1 ft for 1 ft for.

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills if this isn't the correct math for Grappling Move Speed.

To answer the OP: You've spent your 30' of movement because those 15' cost you 2' per 1'.