# How does a Slowed creature move through caltrops?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, equipment

Moving through difficult terrain seems to [negate the need to make a saving throw for ball bearings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152660/how-do-ball-bearings-and-difficult-terrain-stack) and by extension, caltrops. Because

> You move at **half speed** in difficult terrain— moving 1 foot in
> Difficult Terrain costs 2 feet of speed

and Caltrops say:

> Any creature that enters the area must succeed on a DC 15 Dexterity
> saving throw or stop moving and take 1 piercing damage. Until the
> creature regains at least 1 hit point, its walking speed is reduced by
> 10 feet. **A creature moving through the area at half speed doesn't need
> to make the saving throw.**

If I understand the clause about difficult terrain correctly, “moving at half speed” technically means spending 2 ft of remaining movement to move 1 ft. But, there are some spells like "Slow" or ["Spirit Guardians"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137950/how-do-i-apply-half-speed-for-the-spirit-guardians-spell) that have the effect of "halving speed”, in a different sense.

Slow:

> An **affected target's speed is halved**, it takes a -2 penalty to AC
> and Dexterity Saving Throws, and it can't use reactions.

“Halved speed” in this sense seems to have a technical definition that involves dividing the creature's speed by 2.

So, under the effects of a Slow spell, how would these effects interact? Can I ignore the caltrops as I would in difficult terrain? Or would I make the saving throw at disadvantage? Would the effects compound such that my speed was halved AND each foot cost 2ft? And, finally, how would the secondary effect of caltrops

> Until the
> creature regains at least 1 hit point, its walking speed is reduced by
> 10 feet.

reduce my Slowed/original speed?